# Splitting Auto Generated Code File into individual class files

Tags: c#, formatting

I have a large code file generated by XSD.exe, which has generated a 40k file, with many hundreds of class definitions in it. This is because there are about 30 Root XSD's and a few common ones, and they all need to be bundled together to import.

I'd like to split them into seperate classe files so they can be managed easily. Is there any easy way to do this, or am I going to have to resort so some kind of Regex Voodoo?

Cheers

Tristan

Comment: What's the benefit of splitting the classes?  How often will you need to look at the generated code?  I would think that splitting them out would make versioning them more painful.

Comment: can you give an example of a generated class?

Answer (score 3):

You could use ReSharper to do this:

Right-Click on the generated File
 --> Refactor
   --> Move Types into matching Files

If you dont have ReSharper, you could retrieve an evaluation copy at http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

regards,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

If they're generated as `public partial class ClassName` you can create another `public partial class ClassName` wherever you like to add additional members.

With most of these **autogenerating-class-tools** they dump them all in one file because you typically don't want to edit these classes since if the tool is ran again it will overwrite your changes.

If you can generate partial classes with the tool then you should be good to go.